# JMESPath filter/MultiSelect on a large JSON file

Tags: python, jmespath

Datasource is a Juniper Router routing table output in json (> 3 GB json file). What I finally would like to have is being able to loop over a list of prefixes and get the prefix as-path combination.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
from jmespath import search

jsonData = """{
  "route-information": [
    {
      "route-table": [
        {
          "rt": [
            {
              "rt-destination": [
                {
                  "data": "2001:db8:1::/48"
                }
              ],
              "rt-entry": [
                {
                  "as-path": [
                    {
                      "data": "64511 65551 I"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "rt-destination": [
                {
                  "data": "2001:db8:2::/48"
                }
              ],
              "rt-entry": [
                {
                  "as-path": [
                    {
                      "data": "65536 64496 I"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}"""

data = json.loads(jsonData)

query='"route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[].{\"destination\": \"rt-destination\", path: \"rt-entry\"}'

output = search(query, data)
print(output)
```

the above `query` results in:

```
[{'destination': [{'data': '2001:db8:1::/48'}], 'path': [{'as-path': [{'data': '64511 65551 I'}]}]}, {'destination': [{'data': '2001:db8:2::/48'}], 'path': [{'as-path': [{'data': '65536 64496 I'}]}]}]
```

Looks like on the right way. But I would to have the *prefix* : *as-path* combination, so I would like to get rid of the "data:" and "as-path.data" part (in the actual json file there are many more objects on this level and I try to get rid of them here).

```
query='"route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[].{\"destination\": \"rt-destination\", path: \"rt-entry\".\"as-path\"}
```

and/or

```
query='"route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[].{\"destination\": \"rt-destination\", path: \"rt-entry\".\"as-path\".data}'
```

results in:

```
[{'destination': [{'data': '2001:db8:1::/48'}], 'path': None}, {'destination': [{'data': '2001:db8:2::/48'}], 'path': None}]
```

Any ideas why "None" and or/how to proceed?

Another idea was filtering:

```
query='"route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[?"rt-destination".data==`2001:db8:2::/48`]'
```

and then working my way further down to get the as-path. But the query results in `[[]]` where as

```
query='"route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[?"rt-destination".data=="2001:db8:2::/48"]'
```

leads to

```
[[{'rt-destination': [{'data': '2001:db8:1::/48'}], 'rt-entry': [{'as-path': [{'data': '64511 65551 I'}]}]}, {'rt-destination': [{'data': '2001:db8:2::/48'}], 'rt-entry': [{'as-path': [{'data': '65536 64496 I'}]}]}]]
```

so no filtering at all.

Comment: An example of the JSON you are aiming to get would be better here than your long and quite unclear description: *so I would like to get rid of the "data:" and "as-path.data" part*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have a set of data looking like this:

```json
[
  {
    "destination":  "2001:db8:1::/48",
    "path": "64511 65551 I"
  },
  {
    "destination": "2001:db8:2::/48",
    "path": "65536 64496 I"
  }
]
```

It can simply be achieved with this query:

```
route-information[].route-table[].rt[].{
  destination: rt-destination[0].data, 
  path: rt-entry[0].as-path[0].data
}
```

---

But I suspect, with the lists you have under `rt-destination`, `rt-entry` and `as-path`, that this query might actually make you miss some data.

Here is one that is less likely going to make you miss data but that is creating a list under `path`, so the resulting JSON looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "destination": [
      "2001:db8:1::/48"
    ],
    "path": [
      "64511 65551 I"
    ]
  },
  {
    "destination": [
      "2001:db8:2::/48"
    ],
    "path": [
      "65536 64496 I"
    ]
  }
]
```

And the query is:

```
route-information[].route-table[].rt[].{
  destination: rt-destination[*].data, 
  path: rt-entry[*].as-path[*].data | [] 
}
```

This query makes use of the flatten operator `|`, which is explained in the examples under [working with nested data](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#working-with-nested-data).

---

Here is a script demonstrating this:

```py
import jmespath
from pprint import pprint

data = {
  "route-information": [
    {
      "route-table": [
        {
          "rt": [
            {
              "rt-destination": [
                {
                  "data": "2001:db8:1::/48"
                }
              ],
              "rt-entry": [
                {
                  "as-path": [
                    {
                      "data": "64511 65551 I"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "rt-destination": [
                {
                  "data": "2001:db8:2::/48"
                }
              ],
              "rt-entry": [
                {
                  "as-path": [
                    {
                      "data": "65536 64496 I"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

query = [
    '''
    "route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[].{
        destination: "rt-destination"[0].data,
        path: "rt-entry"[0]."as-path"[0].data
    }
    ''',
    '''
    "route-information"[]."route-table"[].rt[].{
        destination: "rt-destination"[*].data,
        path: "rt-entry"[*]."as-path"[*].data | []
    }
    '''
]

pprint(jmespath.search(query[0], data))
print('---------------------------')
pprint(jmespath.search(query[1], data))
```

Prints:

```json
[{'destination': '2001:db8:1::/48', 'path': '64511 65551 I'},
 {'destination': '2001:db8:2::/48', 'path': '65536 64496 I'}]
---------------------------
[{'destination': ['2001:db8:1::/48'], 'path': ['64511 65551 I']},
 {'destination': ['2001:db8:2::/48'], 'path': ['65536 64496 I']}]
```